# Visual Studio online project does not recognize that it has local Git repository?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I created local git repository from existing project and then pushed it to my Visual Studio online project (my code was successfully uploaded to Visual Studio online project).

Now when I connect to my project from Visual Studio 2013 client, Team explorer shows me that I have to clone my repository before I can start developing.

If I write in powershell to check remote repository for my local repository - it shows correct Visual Studio Online project with both fetch and pull rights...

$git remote -v

How can I make Visual Studio recognize, that I already have local repository for this VSO project (the local repository from which I pushed code to VSO)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange - when I closed and reopened Visual Studio 2013, now Visual Studio recognizes that my Team project **HAS** already local repository

This seems strange, because if I have Visual Studio with team project open and I do some changes from poweshell client - they ARE reflected in the Visual Studio side - no VS restart required.